# Copy python output to an excel file

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to concat the first column of one excel file(Train) and predicted column(y_pred) to another excel file. I Get the following error. pls help

## im coding on google collab.

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Here's my code `pd.concat([X_train.iloc[:,0],y_pred,pred_Probability],axis=1).to_csv("/gdrive/My Drive/results.csv", index = None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this, and see if it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[X_train.iloc[:,0],y_pred,pred_Probability])    
df.to_csv("/gdrive/My Drive/results.csv", index = None)
```